# How to configure SSIS 2012 project to run under different environment configurations?

Tags: deployment, ssis, sql-server-2012

What would be the best logical way of configuring 2012 SSIS project using the **Project Deployment Model**?

Consider a scenario of an SSIS Project `MyImport-Project` having three packages

#### Project solution:

- MyImport-Project

  - Import-Package-01
  - Import-Package-02
  - Import-Package-03

#### Project Variables:

- Project-DBConnString : used by all packages to connecting to a single database.
- Project-FolderPath   : used by all packages to lookup input files

#### Environments:

The project gets deployed on

- QA server
- Staging server
- Production server

Is there a standard method of configuring project parameters ?

I saw quite a few articles on Configuration  Files for packages. Is there a way to configure Project Parameters depending on the deployment environment ?

Comment: Are you looking to take advantage of the new Project deployment model for SSIS 2012 or is this using the existing Package deployment model?

Comment: I am using the Project deployment model. I should have mentioned this in the question

Comment: @frictionlesspulley Which answer below provides the most accurate description of what you want to achieve?  Perhaps select one as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

SSIS 2012 project deployment model provides greater flexibility to create Environments and configure environment specific values, which can mapped to project parameters. Here is a sample that illustrates how you can execute a package deployed to *`Integration Services Catalog`* against multiple environments. Ideally, production environment should be on its own server. This example uses all the environments on the same server for simplicity.

#### SSIS 2012 Integration Services Catalog with environment specific values:

Let's assume that you have deployed a package to Integration Services Catalog with two project parameters named *`Environment`* and *`FilePath`*. To run the package under different environments, you can create multiple environments under **`Integration Services Catalogs \ SSIDB \ Folder name \ Environments`**

This sample has three Environment folders named **`DEV`**, **`PRD`** and **`TST`**

[image: Environment Folders]

To create variables that should later be mapped to the project parameters, double-click the environment under the Environments folder. This samples shows how to configure values in all environments.

Since, the package has two project parameters named *`Environment`* and *`FilePath`*, we will create two environment variables of the same name. All the environments are configured with *`same`* variable names but with *`different`* values.

[image: DEV Environment]

[image: TST Environment]

[image: PRD Environment]

To map the environment variables to the project parameters, right-click on the project under the Integration Services Catalog and click **`Configure...`**

[image: Project Configure]

On the *Configure* dialog, click **`References`** page and add each environment which should be associated with the project.

[image: Configure References]

On the *Configure* dialog, click **`Parameters`** page. For each parameter listed under *`Parameters`* tab, you need to click the *`Ellipsis`* button to map the appropriate environment variable.

[image: Configure Parameters]

On the Set Parameter Value dialog, select Use environment variable radiobutton and choose the appropriate variable. Here the parameter being mapped is *`[Practice.SSDT].[Environment]`*. Hence, it is being mapped against the environment variable **`Environment`**.

[image: Set Parameter Value]

Once you have mapped the parameter against the appropriate environment variable, you can choose the correct environment during package execution. To execute the package, right-click on the package and click **`Execute...`**

[image: Execute Package]

On the *Execute Package* dialog, check **`Environment`** box and select the appropriate environment from which the package should use the values for execution.

[image: Execute Package]

The sample package *`SO_15206184.dtsx`* in this example simply inserts the values of project parameters *`Environment`* and *`FilePath`* into a table. Here are the results of the package execution against different environments, even the one including from within SSDT.

[image: Package Execution Results]

Answer (score 13):

From my reading of your question, you have 3 separate servers to deploy to, each with it's own instance of the SSIS Catalog. You do not want a single server to execute for multiple environments. For that scenario, user756519's answer is of little use unfortunately - 10 out of 10 for effort though.

I would ignore the "Environments" setup in SSIS. This is for managing multiple environments on a single SQL Server instance.

Instead I would:

1. set the Environment 1 Project Parameter values in the Visual Studio solution and deploy to Environment 1
2. Deploy to Environment 2
3. Use SSMS to connect to Environment 2, navigate Under Integration Services Catalogs to find your project, right-click it and choose Configure. Edit the parameters as required for Environment 2
4. Deploy to Environment 3
5. Use SSMS to connect to Environment 3, navigate Under Integration Services Catalogs to find your project, right-click it and choose Configure. Edit the parameters as required for Environment 3

You can now continue to develop and deploy your project to each environment. No further maintenance is required, unless you add/delete/rename a Project Parameter. When any package is executed on each Environment/server, it will follow the configuration set via SSMS

Comment: Could you check if the last edit on your post was in your sense. Ping me to delete the comment.

Comment: @jmsmcfrlnd the last edit, now visible on the answer, in my eyes the are massive and I just wanted Mike to have a view on it.

Comment: @jmsmcfrlnd you may roll it back, but I'd just let Mike decide it, he should be informed if there are comments on his answer.

Comment: @Mike - I apologize for the over-zealous edit, please feel free to reject prior revision (I would roll it back, but haven't the required rep yet).

Comment: @jmsmcfrlnd - I could reject so I've just edited it back.  Hopefully that sticks.  IMO the whole idea of editing anyone elses writing is inapproriate for SO and should be turned off.