# SSIS Package Deployment Model : Could not find connection managers

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using Package Deployment Model for one of my project in SSIS.

When I am importing the package on SSISDB under Integration Service Catalogs. [image]

It imports successfully.

Then, I want to create a Job under SQL Job Agents to Run this Package periodically. But there I am not getting any Connection managers which I have used in my package.

My SSIS package has 2 connections :

1. Connection to the Sharepoint Site (Which is the source of the data)
2. Connection to the SQL Server ( Which is the destination of the data)

If I am not getting the connection manager while creating the job, then How can I change the connection Servers from local to Production ones from here?

Am I missing something on configuration part to include Connection Managers in the Deployment Package?

Please help here.

Thank you,
Mittal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS open the `Integration Services Catalogs -> SSISDB -> CatalogName -> Projects`, then right click on the project OR `Find the package in the SSIS Catalog` and right click on it, then select the `Configure...` entry in the popup menu.

You can select the package in the `Scope` dropdown list, then you can find the connections under the `Connection Managers` tab.

Also please read this thread: [How to configure SSIS 2012 project to run under different environment configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206184/how-to-configure-ssis-2012-project-to-run-under-different-environment-configurat)

Comment: Thank you for the response and I will go through this link for connections manager.  I want to deploy the ispac file to create the Project under SSISDB in service catalogs. But while deployment I am getting the below error. Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '100153'.  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27203)  Any idea about this ?

Comment: This is a new question. Did you executed the query mentioned? In the original question, you are talking about Package Deployment Model, now you are talking about Projects. If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question by clicking on the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Thank you. I will open up the new Question for this Query.