# Edit Project.Params outside visual studio data tools SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, file, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

Hi is there a way to edit the package.params file in a SSIS solution without visual studio?

Comment: You open the file with an editor and well, you edit it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there are no external applications needed you can do it through environment variables and SSMS You can read the full article here

[How to configure SSIS 2012 project to run under different environment configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206184/how-to-configure-ssis-2012-project-to-run-under-different-environment-configurat)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that what you're wanting to do is set a new value for the package parameters at runtime. You can set these in the package store or in the execution settings, http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables .