# How to configure connection manager when executing dtsx from a sqlserver job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, connection, sql-agent-job

I have a SSIS project with several SSIS packages. They run correctly on my local development machine, where they connect to my local DB through a Connection Manager that connects with windows authentication to "localhost".

Now I copy the .dtsx file on a Server and I create a Job that, as only step, launches the dtsx.
I need to change the connection of the dtsx but in "new job step" i don't see any tab where i can modify it. For instance, in "Data Sources" there is an empty list with columns "connection manager, description, connection string".  Shouldnt my connection manager appear here and be editable?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an SSIS Catalog. Config-Management gets a lot easier. See this awesomely answered SO-Question: [How to configure SSIS 2012 project to run under different environment configurations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206184/how-to-configure-ssis-2012-project-to-run-under-different-environment-configurat)

Comment: Yeah, I did this on another machine where SSIS catalog was installed but on THIS machine it is not available. I am using a xml Configuration file but i run into the problem that i can't specify a parameter that i need. there are loads and loads of possible configuration but i can't have the value of a PROJECT parameter nor the value of a PACKAGE parameter to show in the configuration file.

Comment: Is it an older Version of SQL Server? Then you'll have to use Package Configuration files, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx